# Log the output of ssh shell and preserve the exit status

Tags: bash, shell-script, pipe, exit-status

I have some script to be executed on remote server(`server-2`) through ssh from `server-1` and I have to write that output into a log file named `file.log` on `server-1`.

I am trying this: `sc.sh`

```
echo 'testing'
cp $HOME/dir1/file1 $HOME/dir2
```

Now, executing the `sc.sh` through ssh:

```
sshpass -p 'psswd' ssh username@server-2 "bash -s" < sc.sh | tee -a file.log
if [ $? -eq 0]; then
  echo "successfully executed the script file"
  .
  .
  .
else
  echo "failed copying due to incorrect path"
fi
```

Now because of `tee -a file.log` command, it will always return 0 even though my commands in script file fails. How can I write into log file and should check the if condition after `ssh` command which should work based on the `ssh` commands exit code?

Comment: In case you are using bash, see `man bash` -> `PIPESTATUS`. Also see `pipefail`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

checking `${PIPESTATUS[0]}` worked for me...

```
if [ ${PIPESTATUS[0]} -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "successfull"
fi
```

`echo ${PIPESTATUS[*]}` prints the exit codes of all the pipeline commands.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to : "how to log the output of ssh shell?" is

- use a simple redirect >

e.g.

```
ssh user@remote_host "command" > local_log_file.txt
```

or

```
sshpass -p 'psswd' ssh username@server-2 "echo 'testing'; cp dir1/file1 dir2;" > local_machine_ssh_log.txt
```

If you want to check the result of the `cp` cmmand on the remote server, I'd suggest running the *if statement* on the remote host as part of the command you send, immediately after running the `cp` command

something like:

```
sshpass -p 'psswd' ssh username@server-2 "echo 'testing'; cp dir1/file1 dir2;if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then   echo "successfully copied"; else   echo "failed copying due to incorrect path"; fi" > local_machine_ssh_log.txt
```

Comment: But i have few commands to run on this server-1 immediately after `cp` command.

Comment: @EjjagiriVenkatesh - what exactly would you like to do, and check using the `if` statement?

Comment: in the place of commands i have to send a script file sometimes to execute, in that case how can we check. I have to check if all the commands in the sent script file are executed successfully or not? How can i check and log the output?

Comment: @EjjagiriVenkatesh - can you check the local_output.txt file in your local machine?

Comment: edited my question, can you please give me solution for this?